# Display USB current transfer speed on Android

Tags: android, usb

I'm looking for a program that can display the current transfer speed (if possible up and down) on the USB port on Android. Free and without root needed is better. I'm especially interested in the case of a connected computer to an Android device to transfer files: I would like to know how fast the transfer is with a solution that runs on Android (not on the computer).

I use a rooted Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.2 and a rooted Nexus 7 with Android 4.4.2.

Comment: Is this for a connected flash drive, or a tethered computer? or a connected computer and being used to transfer files? - either way, this would likely need to be an app with root access in order to function

Comment: @user2813274 connected computer and being used to transfer files. Requiring a root access is okay.